# How to insert a string into another string after the first (and only the first) ocurrence of a character

Tags: python, regex, string

Using Python3 I need to insert the string `BA|` on each line of a file like this one:

```
AZ|C|DTD
E|GS|H
```

But only after the first occurrence of `|`. So, after inserting the string, the file should look like this:

```
AZ|BA|C|DTD
E|BA|GS|H
```

I could try inserting a string into another at a certain position, but the length of the words is not regular. I could insert the string after finding `|` but that could result in inserting the string more than once in the same line.

Comment: Only find the first | and insert it ?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried so far.

Comment: [You may use `repl = re.sub(r'^([^|]+)', '$1|BA', str)`](https://regex101.com/r/T4r4sz/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str.replace()`.

```
for line in file:
   line = line.replace("|", "|BA|", 1)
   # print line, write it to new file, etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

`line.index('|')` gives the first occurrence

```
outfile = open('outfile.txt', 'w')
for line in open('inputfile.txt'):
    split_index = line.index('|')
    line = line[:split_index] + '|BA' + line[:split_index]
    outfile.write(line)
```

or do it with split

```
outfile = open('outfile.txt', 'w')
for line in open('inputfile.txt'):
    line = line.split('|')
    line.insert(1, 'BA')
    line = '|'.join(line)
    outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Regex for this. Using `str.partition`:

```
In [87]: str_ = 'AZ|C|DTD'

# Gets the partitions spitted on first `|`
# generates 3 element tuple: `('AZ', '|', 'C|DTD')`
In [88]: parts = str_.partition('|')

# Concatenate after joining first two elements with
# empty string, `BA|` and last element
In [89]: ''.join(parts[:2]) + 'BA|' + parts[2]
Out[89]: 'AZ|BA|C|DTD'
```

---

For a file:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.strip().partition('|')
        new_line = ''.join(parts[:2]) + 'BA|' + parts[2]
```